# int values in char array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of chars:

```
char **f = new char* [size+1];
for (int i = 0; i < size+1; i++) {
    f [i] = new char [size1];
    for (int j = 0; j < size1; j++) {
        f[i][j] = '_';
        cout << f[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

How can I add int value to represent numbers of lines and columns?

The output should be something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
...
```

I suppose the best way is to convert integers j and i to char and add them. But I do not want to use Unicode, since i and j might be greater than 9. Could you recommend me a better way? Thank you!

Comment: Why aren't you using a vector of strings?

Comment: Also, can you please edit the question to show the output you want?

Comment: The point of the task is to use pointers

Comment: Why aren't you just using the indices i and j itself?

Comment: Why not print the column header in a separate loop before the first loop you have now?

Comment: The idea came to me too, but it seemed a bit not rational. I thought there is a way to put int values into char array...

Comment: Dear Tobias, what you mean by using indices, like printing them separately?

Comment: Yes, same what Joachim Pileborg said. If you want to print row and column numbers, you could print the row header line first inside your for (i..), and print the row index as first step inside your for (j..). Don't need to put that data into the array before printing. I also wouldn't, as you changed your data array in this case, which might not be intended.

Comment: BTW: a `char` variable is a byte and can hold values from 0 to 255. As long as you don't want to go any further, `char` is completely sufficient. You would save the row/column number in that char, not it's text representation.